# How to easily use additional, special characters in file names and the like?

Tags: fonts, special-characters, filenames

We see this again and again in filenames of Youtube downloads, even from kids, so there must be a very simple solution to my question: very special characters which definitely are not contained in the character set of the used standard font (whatever it is), for example little pictures and the like.

I would like to use such non-standard characters not for fun, as they do, but for quick identification of list entries, for example a big red or blue square as first character of the (otherwise standard black) file name or list entry, for example in file managers or lists of browser bookmarks and the like.

I have searched standard fonts for the possible position / ISO code of such special signs, but to no avail, and it's obvious those kids don't get to them by opening fonts with special tools, then inserting their own pics as characters into them, but perhaps they combine two fonts in some filename entry, or something, I have searched the web by numerous search wordings, and I don't get a solution; also here, in "Similar questions" and 29 "answers", all of them have nothing to do with my problem, i.e. neither google AI nor stackoverflow AI can identify it from my question / description.

Comment: Those "little pictures" are called emoji, and have been part of standard Unicode for quite a while now. Don't look "in fonts", just type them, using your OS's emoji input (Windows: `Start` +`.`, MacOS: `Control` + `Command` + `Spacebar`, Linux/Unix: you're on your own, but you already know where to go to look this up for your distro)

Comment: So why don't I find them in the ISO character set of the font? And how would I insert them in file names, in any given file manager? What would be (I'm on Windows) "Start plus Dot"? When I open the start menu and then enter a dot, I do not get any "emoij", all the less into any filename.

Comment: (1) because just like every other unicode block: only fonts that support emoji support emoji, just like how you're not going to find Sinhalese in Times New Roman. Your OS is smart enough to pick a font that supports emoji when it needs to render them. (2) you use your OS's emoji input. See above.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, this is real help indeed. Now I search for "Windows emojis", "black square emoji", etc., and I get real results finally, I have also been able to insert such an emoji into a filename. In W10, by Win-plus-dot, I get an emoji list which of course does NOT contain the emojis I need; I am now looking for ways to get those into that Windows dialogue; in the end, accessing them by a shortkey would be fine. But thank you really very much for having me sent onto the correct way of searching. (This was really kid knowledge, totally unknown to me.)

Comment: The Windows dialogue (Win-Dot) works, in some way. Squares and triangles are to be found by the "heart" category symbol, and then used symbols (a click on them inserts them) will be put onto the stack of the ones displayed under the category "clock" symbol ("Recently used"). They do not necessarily appear as expected though, e.g. in Arial (RTF editor, file manager), black remains black, but blue or red appear as grey, or red, green, yellow appear as white, with just a grey outline, but this is a BIG step ahead all the same, thank you very much again, Mike!

Comment: And in the Firefox bookmarks sidebar, e.g. Red even remains red: heureka! You can't set those bookmark entries to "bold", so big (e.g.) red squares in front of the entries help enormously, to distinguish important ones. (I had first asked in the FF forum, but no help there, just the confirmation that it was not possible to use a specific (e.g. bold) font for just some of the entries.)

Comment: I’m going to vote to close this question because this wasn't a programming question, and emoji have been standard fare for years now.

Comment: Yep, and once people know what to look up - I obviously didn't -, their reference would be http://www.iemoji.com/emoji-cheat-sheet/symbols and its sub-pages anyway.

Comment: or emojipedia, or any number of other long-standing websites to help with the task of finding a particular emoji.